# Unable to load the FDO provider library Postgresqlprovider.dll on Autodesk Civil 3D

Tags: postgis, postgresql, civil3d

I created a PostGIS database on a server called "aisrv2" on the standard port 5432.
Connecting from QGIS the connection works using *Host*, *Port* and *Databse name*, so I wanted to do the same in Civil 3d 2023
through the tool 'Add PostgreSQL Connection' in Map Connect Menu, but I get the error

> Unable to load the FDO Provider library ‘PostgreSQLProvider.dll

In Civil 3D I'm prompted for the *service name* like you might enter in QGIS and as I read on Autodesk support [here](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-Unable-to-load-the-FDO-Provider-library-PostgreSQLProvider-dll-in-Map-3D-or-Civil-3D-2020.html?_ga=2.121780303.595971745.1681723300-1085595957.1681723300), I set the service parameters as shown in the image (`host.name:port_number`) and copied the file `libpq.dll` from the server to the specified path (in my case I don't have the files libeay32 and ssleay32.dll).

But I always get the same error.

I'm using PostgreSQL v.15 (x64) on a Windows Server 2012R2

[image]

What can I try to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the very same problem for some time now, and finally managed to get things working. Here's how I did it:

- You need to install PostgreSQL and PostGIS* *on the computer you are connecting to Postgres from.* Even if you are connecting to a remote server. No need to configure it further or set up any databases, just have it installed.
- [You need to add the Postgres bin folder](https://trac.osgeo.org/fdo/wiki/FdoPostgreSQLNotes) (`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version-nr>\bin`) to the [PATH environment variable](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-PATH-Environment-Variable-on-Windows)
- [As per this Autodesk help article](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAP/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-4476AD90-FD33-41EA-9DC7-C8EAE04B9C7F), `libpq.dll` won't be sufficient, you need to copy `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to the same folder as well. `1_1` here also stands for version number, your installation might have it different but it should work regardless.

*Note: Installing PostGIS might not be neccessary. Unfortunately, I was not able to thoroughly test this due to workload; but I'll come back and edit this answer once I find the time to do it.